# C# System.Windows.Forms.Shortcut to display String (Ex. CtrlX -> Ctrl+X)

Tags: c#, winforms, menuitem

I'm trying to customize MenuItem via OwnerDraw, and now I'm having an issue when a MenuItem contains a shortcut key. I already formulated to get the exact point to put their respective shortcuts, but I can't get the exact shortcut string. I tried to to use this code:

```
var keyConverter = new KeysConverter();
var shotcutString = keyConverter.ConvertToString(System.Windows.Forms.Shortcut.CtrlX);
```

But the result it displays is "CtrlX" not "Ctrl+X".

Now, I would like to ask how to convert shortcut (System.Windows.Forms.Shortcut) to their display string value? (Example: CtrlX > "Ctrl+X").

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To use `KeysConverter` you should cast `Shortcut` to `Keys`. Also you should check for shortcut key `Shortcut.None` and return `string.Empty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [`KeysConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) you should cast [`Shortcut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.shortcut(v=vs.110).aspx) to [`Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) . Also you should check for shortcut key `Shortcut.None` and return `string.Empty`. You can use this method:

```
public string ShortcutToText(Shortcut shortcutKeys)
{
    if (shortcutKeys == Shortcut.None)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    return new KeysConverter().ConvertToString((Keys)shortcutKeys);
}
```

For example:

```
MessageBox.Show(ShortcutToText(System.Windows.Forms.Shortcut.CtrlX));
```

Shows `Ctrl+X`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `KeysConverter.ConvertToString` default behavior is doing simple `Enum.ToString()` conversion. Try to use `Replace("Ctrl", "Ctrl+")` to further process for `Ctrl`:

```
var keyConverter = new KeysConverter();
var shotcutString = keyConverter.ConvertToString(System.Windows.Forms.Shortcut.CtrlX)
    .Replace("Ctrl", "Ctrl+");
```

You could also concatenate "Shift", "Alt", etc if needed or create list of to-be-checked items to be replaced from "Item" to "Item+":

```
var check = new List<string>() { "Shift", "Ctrl", "Alt" }; //add this as needed
foreach (var s in check)
    shotcutString = shotcutString.Replace(s, s + "+");
```